# Use DirectX for Android

Tags: android, graphics, directx

I want to know if it's possible to create games for Android using DirectX.

Comment: Direct X is windows specific and as far as I know works only on windows devices . OpenGL is open source hence it is used for Android and  other linux distros. If you really want to learn something books are the best , read a book on the topic of your choice

Comment: iOS and Android apps are written with OpenGL ES 2.0, and the [ANGLE](https://code.google.com/p/angleproject/) library lets you use that same code on Windows platforms.

Comment: If you are completely new to games & graphics and you are running a Windows system, then learn how with DirectX and you can learn OpenGL ES 2.0 for Android later once you know what you are doing. See the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) as a good place to start for Direct3D 11. Targeting phones and consoles is challenging, so most folks have PC builds of their games for testing & development even if they never intended to actually ship for PC.

Comment: Alternatively, just use something like Unity.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. @ChuckWalbourn i have some experience  with Unity (like 2 or 3 years).